# Use of jquery noconflict function when including external js libraries and js code files

Tags: javascript, jquery, external

Does one need to use jquery noconflict() method in the following

situation.

```
`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jq180customcode.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="jq171customcode.js"></script>`
```

The above situation is when we use different jquery libraries in a 
single page and load external files with custom code specific to the 
the library mentioned above it.

If one does need to use the jquery noconflict method please show how to 
use it.

Here jq180customcode and jq171customcode external javascript files contains script functions which are written keeping in mind the external libraries jq-1.8.0 and jq-1.7.1 libraries respectively that is "jq180customcode.js" contains functions specific for the html page which are created in accordance with "jq-1.8.0.js" and "jq171customcode.js" contains functions specific for the html page which are created in accordance with "jq-1.7.1.js". I specifically want to know whether one needs to use jquery.noconflict in these "customcode" files and if one has to use it how?

Comment: A much better solution is **not** to use multiple copies of jQuery on the same page. Just use one. Ideally something more recent than either of those.

Answer (score 0):

A much better solution is **not** to use multiple copies of jQuery on the same page. Just use one. Ideally something more recent than either of those.

But if you really want to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jq180customcode.js"></script>
<script>
var jq180 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jq171customcode.js"></script>
<script>
var jq171 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Note that it's important that `jq180customcode.js` grab a copy of the `jQuery` and/or `$` symbol **right away** and store it. One good way is like this:

```
(function($) {
    // The code here
})(jQuery);
```

Within `The code here`, the code can use `$` to refer to the jQuery that was present when the code was loaded.

In scripts **after** all of the above, you'd use `jq180` or `jq171` depending on which copy of jQuery you want to use.

You could leave one or the other `noConflict` off, of course, and use `jQuery` (and `$`) for the other one. For instance (reordering things slightly):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jq171customcode.js"></script>
<script>
var jq171 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jq180customcode.js"></script>
```

Now, you'd use `jq171` for jQuery v1.7.1 and either `jQuery` or `$` for jQuery v1.8.0.

---

Here's a live example of using v1.7.1 and v1.8.0:

```html
<input id="btn1" type="button" value="Click to see jQuery v1.8.0 in use">
<br><input id="btn2" type="button" value="Click to see jQuery v1.7.1 in use">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // Custom v1.8.0 stuff
  (function($) {
    $("#btn1").click(function() {
      $("<p>jQuery version: " + $.fn.jquery + "</p>").appendTo(document.body);
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
<script>
  var jq180 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // Custom v1.7.1 stuff
  (function($) {
    $("#btn2").click(function() {
      $("<p>jQuery version: " + $.fn.jquery + "</p>").appendTo(document.body);
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
<script>
  var jq171 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
```